# What can be done with the "constraint" keyword in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, typing, parametric-polymorphism

[The OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual016.html) describes the "constraint" keyword, which can be used in a type definition. However, I cannot figure out any usage that can be done with this keyword. When is this keyword is useful? Can it be used to remove polymorphic type variables? (so that a `type 'a t` in a module becomes just `t` and the module can be used in a functor argument which requires `t` with no variables.)

Comment: Don't have time to write something up, but you may find leo whites' recent response on row-polymorphism helpful. https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/caml-list/2014-06/msg00059.html

Comment: An example has been given in the previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486948/subtype-constraints-in-interfaces

Comment: You can also use it with polymorphic variants.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm not really confortable with ocaml classes. Do you have any example which doesn't involve them ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So, the `constraint` keywords, used in type or class definitions, let one "reduce the scope” of applicable types to a type parameter, so to speak. The documentation clearly announce that type expressions from both sides of the constraint equation will be unified to "refine" the types the constraint relates to. Because they are type expressions, you may use all the usual type level operators.

Examples:

```
# type 'a t = int * 'a constraint 'a * int = float * int;;
type 'a t = int * 'a constraint 'a = float

# type ('a,'b) t = 'c r constraint 'c = 'a * 'b
    and 'a r = {v1 : 'a; v2 : int };;
type ('a,'b) t = ('a * 'b) r
and 'a r = { v1 : 'a; v2 : int; }
```

Observe how type unification simplifies the equations, in the first example by getting rid of the extraneous type product (`* int`), and in the second case eliminating it altogether. Note also that I used a type variable `'c` which only appears in the right hand side of the type definition.

Two interesting uses are with polymorphic variants and class types, both based on row-polymorphism. Constraints allow to express certain subtyping relations. By subtyping, for variants, we mean a relation such that any constructor of a type is present in its subtypes. Some of these relations may already be expressed monomorphically:

```
# type sum_op = [ `add | `subtract ];;
type sum_op = [ `add | `subtract ]
# type prod_op = [ `mul | `div ];;
type prod_op = [ `mul | `div ]
# type op = [ sum_op | prod_op ];;
type op = [ `add | `div | `mul | `sub ]
```

There, `op` is a subtype of both `sum_op` and `prod_op`.

But in some cases, you have to introduce polymorphism, and this is where constraints come handy:

```
# type 'a t = 'a constraint [> op ] = 'a;;
type 'a t = 'a constraint 'a = [> op ]
```

The above let you denote the family of types which are subtypes of `op` : the type instance is `'a` itself for a given instance of `'a t`.

If we try to define the same type without a parameter, the type unification algorithm will complain:

```
# type t' = [> op];;
Error: A type variable is unbound in this type declaration.
In type [> op ] as 'a the variable 'a is unbound
```

The same sort of constraints may be expressed with class types, and the same problem may arise if the type definition is implicitly polymorphic by subtyping.

```
# class type ct = object method v : int end;;
class type ct =  object method v : int end
# type i = #ct;;
Error: A type variable is unbound in this type declaration.
In type #ct as 'a the variable 'a is unbound
# type 'a i = 'a constraint 'a = #ct;;
type 'a i = 'a constraint 'a = #ct
```

Comment: Thank you for this very clear answer. I feel very uncomfortable, because the usage you give seems to only fix a weakness in the original type system. I know I am probably wrong, but I can't understand why it is not possible to define directly "open types" without using the "constraint" keyword. After all, the compiler use this type when typing a match with a default case.

Comment: What do you mean by open types? Are you refering to the `#` notation for class interfaces?

Comment: My opinion is that the original type system, which let define new types with the `type ...` notation, did not handle subtyping. That came from the set of type constructors available before the object language came along, but with that new language in, a way was needed to concile both type languages. So there might be a slight feeling of ”bolted on” with it. I don't know how this could have been done otherwise.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I didn't want to write "open type" but "open union" which is a term I read somewhere for the [> ...] notation.

Comment: This answer seems to have the subtype relation for polymorphic variants reversed. `sum_op` and `prod_op` are subtypes of `op`, not the other way, and `[> op]` refers to supertypes of `op`, not subtypes. A variant type is a (width) subtype of another (can be used where the other is expected) if it supports *less* constructors.